# Uniqueness of Isomorphism $M \otimes_A N \cong N \otimes_A M$ (Proposition 2.14 in Atiyah-Macdonald).

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Proposition $2.14$ in Atiyah-Macdonald states that there is a *unique* isomorphism between $M \otimes_A N$ and $N \otimes_A M$ for any two $A$-modules $M$ and $N$. Here is a picture of the relevant passage.

[image: Atiyah-Macdonald 2.14]
 I'm struggling to figure out why the following is not a counterexample to the claim of uniqueness. Take $A=M=N=\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the two maps
\begin{align*}
\phi_1: \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} & \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} \\
x \otimes y & \mapsto x \otimes y
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\phi_2: \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} & \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z} \\
x \otimes y & \mapsto (-x) \otimes y
\end{align*}

As near as I can tell, these constitute a notrivial subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$. Where am I going wrong with my reasoning? Any and all insights are welcome!

Comment: There **isn't** a unique isomorphism.

Comment: Does it say "... such that ..." when it talks about this unique isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, it does in fact. It says "there exists a unique isomorphism $M \otimes_A N \to N \otimes_A M$....such that... $x \otimes y \mapsto y \otimes x$".

Comment: I've added a picture of the relevant passage to my question -- hopefully this clarifies things.

Comment: So, your second example **doesn't** satisfy $x\otimes y\mapsto y\otimes x$.

Comment: Oh, I've just totally misunderstood the statement. They're just saying "the following map is an isomorphism", not "there exists a unique isomorphism and this is it". Now I understand! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Archaick Well, not exactly. Not every element of $N\otimes M$ is of the form $x\otimes y$. So the content of the "unique" part of the statement is that once you specify $x\otimes y\mapsto y\otimes x$, the rest of the map is determined uniquely (just by the fact that it's supposed to be a homomorphism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is essentially Darij's comment; it exists to remove this question from the unanswered queue.

The isomorphisms i, ii, iii, iv given in this proposition are unique up to the properties a, b, c, d (respectively). As your counterexample shows, there generally are many isomorphisms between $M\otimes N$ and $N\otimes M$.